# Invalid syntax when using "print"?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and can't even write the first example:

```
print 2 ** 100
```

this gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

pointing at the 2.

Why is this? I'm using version 3.1

Comment: Where did you find this example?  Is it in a book or a website?

Comment: It might be *Learning Python*.

Comment: jleedev is correct; it is OReilly Learning Python 3rd edition 2007.

Comment: Can also happen in Python 2.x if `from __future__ import print_function` is used. Then, the print functions behave as in Pyhton 3.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

That is because in Python 3, they have replaced the `print` *statement* with the `print` *function*.

The syntax is now more or less the same as before, but it requires parens:

From the "[what's new in python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)" docs:

```
Old: print "The answer is", 2*2
New: print("The answer is", 2*2)

Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline

Old: print              # Prints a newline
New: print()            # You must call the function!

Old: print >>sys.stderr, "fatal error"
New: print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr)

Old: print (x, y)       # prints repr((x, y))
New: print((x, y))      # Not the same as print(x, y)!
```

Comment: See this for more: [Why print statement is not pythonic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053849/why-print-statement-is-not-pythonic)

Answer (score 14):

You need parentheses:

```
print(2**100)
```

Answer (score 8):

They changed `print` in Python 3.  In 2 it was a statement, now it is a function and requires parenthesis.

Here's [the docs from Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is changed in new 3.x releases rather than old 2.x releases:
for example in python 2.x you can write:
print "Hi new world"
but in the new 3.x release you need to use the new syntax and write it like this:
print("Hi new world")

check the documentation:
http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print