# Python: invalid syntax in function print()

Tags: python, syntax, printing

I am using Python 2.7.
When I try to print a simple string to a file, I get the following error:

Syntax error: invalid tuple

Syntax error while detecting tuple

minimal example:

```
fly = open('workfile', 'w')
print('a', file=fly)
```

writing to the same file via `fly.write('a')` works just fine.

Comment: This is essentially the same question, but other way around: [Invalid syntax when using "print"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937491/invalid-syntax-when-using-print)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the Python 3 syntax in Python 2.

In Python 2, it's like this:

```
print >> fly, 'a'
```

However, a better idea is to do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Which will enable the Python 3 syntax if you are using Python 2.6 or 2.7.

See also: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Python 2 documentation gives the same syntax http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

edit: thanks ;)

Comment: @lhcgeneva: Read the note in the link you just linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print)

> Note This function is not normally available as a built-in since the name print is recognized as the print statement. To disable the statement and use the print() function, use this future statement at the top of your module:
>   from **future** import print_function