# npm install parcel installation failed

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, parcel

Running npm install --save-dev parcel in an npm project on my computer returns the following log:

```
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/test/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:457:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/xxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin/node" "/Users/xxxxxx/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/test/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.9.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/xxxxxx/.npm/_logs/2024-02-18T18_19_28_422Z-debug-0.log
```

Not sure how to resolve this. I've read it may be a problem with svgo, I was looking at node-gyp possible issues, but I'm still not sure how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what is your environment? node, npm version

Comment: try installing the parcel globally

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your nodeJs is missing some tools when installing the nodeJs.

Try to reinstall [nodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en) and check the checkbox to install the necessary tools

[image]

Or you can use this command to install the necessary tools without reinstalling nodeJs. But the first solution is better

> Please note that the official Node.js for Windows installer can now automatically install the required tools. That's likely a much better option than the module listed here (windows-build-tools).

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand about your env from attached logs:

1. Your system is probably Mac OS Ventura 13.5
2. Your device is 12 inch MacBook (from 2015 to 2019 year)
3. Your processor is x64
4. NodeJs 20.9.0
5. Node-gyp 3.8.0
6. Python 3.x
7. Probably no XCode or C++ compiler installed

> npm packages in some cases depend on some native modules (C++,
> Python). In your case npm is trying to build python module, and that
> module requires python "2.x" , but in your env is python "3.x"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159415/5138198
Here is an explanation of python error

https://github.com/parcel-bundler/watcher/tree/v2.0.2
Here a module that trigger error

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Here is a module page, and that node module builds python, c++ etc...

> Try to install C++ compiler :
> https://support.wolfram.com/12799?src=system-modeler

OR

> Please read an article about python env at node-gyp page. Or simply
> downgrade your python version to "2.x".
> https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

P.S.
**Parcel -> requires parcel-watcher module (includes C++ files at package) -> requires node-gyp -> node-gyp tries to build "parcel-watcher" and being unable to find C++ compiler and tries alternatively do it through python**

There are all my thoughts

Answer (score 1):

What is your python version?
You need to install python 3 or if you have both version you can set python 3 using npm like this.

```
npm config set python python3
```

Try to update `node-gyp` version.

```
 npm install -g node-gyp
```

Sometimes the npm cache can cause issues.
So clear cache.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And then try to reinstall parcel.

```
npm install --save-dev parcel
```

Comment: And if you are using MacOS, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering indicates an issue with node-gyp, which is used to build native addons for Node.js projects. Here's how to troubleshoot and potentially fix it:

Force Python 3 for node-gyp:

Set the PYTHON environment variable to your Python 3 executable path before running npm install:

```
export PYTHON=/path/to/your/python3  # Replace with actual path
npm install --save-dev parcel
```

Try reinstalling node-gyp globally:

```
npm uninstall -g node-gyp
npm install -g node-gyp
```